# Karate DSL - Need to Pass Current Date and Past Date as Parameters in the POST request

Tags: cucumber, karate

I need to pass current date and past date in a POST request in Karate. This is what I am doing:

In Background I calculate the current date and past date  -
Background:

```
def todaysdate =
      """
      function(curdate){
        var currentDate = new Date();
        karate.log(currentDate);
        return currentDate;
      }
      """
    And def minus30date =
      """
      function(pasdate){
        var pastDate = new Date();
        pastDate.setDate(pastDate.getDate() - 30);
        karate.log(pastDate);
        return pastDate;
      }
      """
```

The above code gives me the dates like this in the console:

```
[Date 2020-07-20T16:18:15.369Z] 
[Date 2020-06-20T16:18:15.379Z]
```

The POST request is in Example section for the scenario outline:

```
| Individual ID Request                                                                   |
| '{  "endDate": "2020-06-20T16:18:15.379Z",  "startDate": "2020-07-20T16:18:15.369Z"  }' |
```

How do I use the return variables in the request for start and end date? I tried putting things like '#(pastDate)' in the request but it does not work. I tried calling the functions in scenario outline and assigning them to a variable and use it in the request but that does not work too.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try passing parameters something like this '<pastDate>'

Comment: pass. this question is too confusing and seems to be 2 different questions in one. simplify it and ask a separate additional question if needed.

Comment: Sorry about that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you date functions can be like modified as below,

```
* def getDate =
"""
function(numberOfDays){
  var date = new Date();
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + (numberOfDays));
  return date.toString()
}
"""
```

after which you can call the function with params like below,

```
* def todaysdate = getDate(0)
* def minus30date = getDate(-30)
* def payload = {"startDate" : "#(todaysdate)", "endDate" : "#(minus30date)"}
```

or

```
* def payload = {"startDate" : "#(getDate(0))", "endDate" : "#(getDate(-30))"}
```

Comment: Thank you!!....That was perfect...exactly what I was looking for....sorry for the messy question.